# When 1 is pressed it should change color right away but I have to click again until it works

Tags: python

I think that the problem has something to do with the scope of the if statement i.e when its run. Not sure how to change this other than moving the code.

```
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Circle color changer", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    win.setBackground('blue')
    counter = 1
    circles = []
    counter2 = 0
    colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "purple"]

    while True:
        if counter < 10:
            point = win.getMouse()
            circ = Circle(point, 40)
            t = Text(circ.getCenter(), f"circle {counter}")
            t.draw(win)
            circ.draw(win)
            circles.append(circ)
            counter += 1
            print(counter)
            print(f" First circle {circles[0], circles}")
           

        key = win.checkKey()
        if key == '1':
            print(f" First circle {circles[0], circles}")
            counter2 += 1
            circles[0].setFill(colors[counter2])

    win.close()

main()
```

I tried moving the below code outside of the while loop but then it would never get ran

```
 if key == '1':
            print(f" First circle {circles[0], circles}")
            counter2 += 1
            circles[0].setFill(colors[counter2])
```

Comment: is `graphics` this : (https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `win.getMouse()` is blocking. This means that your code just sits there waiting for a click and can't do anything else until you click.

I refactored your code a bit to solve your current problem and a bunch of future ones you were about to encounter.

```py
from graphics import *
from collections import deque

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Circle color changer", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    win.setBackground('blue')
    counter = 0
    circles = []

    # rotating a deque is better than index out of range errors
    colors  = deque(("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "purple"))
    
    while True:
        # without this, closing the window with "x" will raise an error
        if win.isClosed(): break
        
        if (key := win.checkKey()) and circles:
            colors.rotate(-1)
            # last circle instead of first one
            circles[-1].setFill(colors[0])
            
        elif (point := win.checkMouse()) and (counter < 10):
            counter += 1
            (circle := Circle(point, 40)).draw(win)
            # draw text AFTER circle so it's in front of it
            Text(circle.getCenter(), f"circle {counter}").draw(win)
            circles.append(circle)

    win.close()

main()
```

graphics.py is just a little wrapper around a tkinter Canvas. It simplifies a few things, but those few things don't have some major learning curve. It will likely be more useful to learn how to directly use tkinter and skip the toy code.